# "Lengthless" fast sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, lua, time-complexity, in-place

I've been looking into sorting algorithms. So far, all the sorting algorithms I've found either rely on a known length (pretty much all sort algos. I can't use them because "proper" length is O(n)), or are slower than quicksort (e.g. insertion sort).

In Lua, there are 2 concepts of length:

- Proper sequence length

  - Is O(n)
  - Used by ipairs etc
- Sequence length

  - Is O(log n)
  - Has holes (nil values)
  - Used by table.insert etc

I've looked into heapsort, but heapsort needs to build a heap, *then* sort. It doesn't do both as a single operation, which means it still suffers from the O(n) length problem.

With insertion sort, you just run the insertion sort algorithm until you hit the first `nil`. This sorts only the "proper sequence" part of a table (that is, the keys from 1 to n without any nil values), but insertion sort is slower than quicksort.

Are there any in-place sorting algorithms that, like insertion sort, don't depend on length, but with performance comparable to that of quicksort?

Example insertion sort code (with some help from wikipedia):

```
function isort(t)
  -- In-place insertion sort that never uses the length operator.
  -- Stops at the first nil, as expected. Breaks if you use "for i = 1, #t do"
  for i in ipairs(t) do
      local j = i
      while j > 1 and t[j-1] > t[j] do
          t[j], t[j-1] = t[j-1], t[j]
          j = j - 1
      end
  end
end

local t = {6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4, nil, 1, 1, 8, 3, 4, nil, nil, 1}
isort(t)
io.write("{")
if #t > 0 then
  io.write(tostring(t[1]))
  for i=2, #t do
    io.write(", ")
    io.write(tostring(t[i]))
  end
end
io.write("}\n")
-- stdout:
-- {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, 1, 1, 8, 3, 4, nil, nil, 1}
```

Comment: exactly how can you sort something if you have no idea how long it is? that's like asking. "I'm on planet Earth. how long does it take to get to Narnia?"

Comment: @MarcB You do know how long it is. Just not in advance.

Comment: insertion sort is about the only algorithm that doesn't care about the length in advance. the rest will need to know SOMETHING about the length, e.g. where to do splitting

Comment: @MarcB Keyword "about the only". While I wait for an answer I'm trying to make my own such algorithm.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. On the face of it, what you're asking is impossible because you have to know the length of the list (array, etc.) if you're going to sort it. But maybe you're trying to maintain the list in sorted order as items are added? If so, then you should look into skip lists, or balanced binary trees. Both of those require O(log n) for insertion, which means that fully populating the data structure has complexity O(n log n). But it won't be as fast as getting the entire list and then running Quicksort.

Comment: @JimMischel How is it unclear? You can write an insertion sort such that it doesn't know the length of the list/array/etc, it just stops at a certain sentinel value. That's basically what I want, except with QS-like speeds.

Comment: So you want to sort, for example, `[1,9,7,14,3,2,12,-1,-1,-1,4,6,...]`, but only sort up to (not including) the first `-1`, which is the sentinel value? And for some unknown reason you don't want to do the O(n) scan to derive the length by finding the first sentinel value? It would be helpful if you provided a simple example so that we all know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: @JimMischel The Lua tag is relevant here. The sentinel value is `nil`.

Comment: @SoniEx2 - Javascript has undefined objects (the equivalent of nil values) and "holes". Take a look at the code in [javascript sort](http://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L902) , it does a scan. I removed my prior and no longer needed comments. Since at least one language uses a O(n) scan as part of it's standard library, it's probably a reasonably efficient approach.

Comment: @rcgldr Javascript has `length`. That code seems to transpose the "garbage" (which I want to ignore) into the array, which is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: @SoniEx2 - my point here and in rici's answer is that a scan to find the length is not that much overhead. As for a sort algorithm that doesn't need to know length in advance, consider a bottom up merge sort:  It can perform it's first pass by swapping elements in place as needed to create sorted pairs until it reaches the end of the data, then follow the normal bottom up merge sort algorithm now that the length is known, but a merge sort needs a second working array (O(n) extra space).

Comment: @SoniEx2 - another sort algorithm that doesn't need to know length in advance is a radix sort, as it performs a scan to determine counts that are converted into offsets for bucket boundaries, but like merge sort, uses a second working array (O(n) extra space) to perform the radix sort. If sorting integers, radix sort would be faster than quick sort. Using 1 byte "digits", 32 bit integers would take 1 scan pass and 4 sort passes.

Comment: @rcgldr: Another option would be a slightly modified shell sort where the first pass finds the correct delta as it proceeds through the array. That will do a few extra compares relative to an unmodified shellsort, but I think (without making any attempt to prove it) that the expected number of extra compares would be small (but linear) compared with `n`, perhaps around n/3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the sort itself must take at least O(n log n), an extra O(n) scan doesn't seem like it would invalidate the algorithm. Using quadratic algorithms such as insertion or bubble sort is false economy.

You could use the heapsort variant where you simply iteratively insert into a growing heap, rather than using the O(n) buildheap algorithm. Heapsort is definitely O(n log n), even if you build the heap incrementally, but I doubt whether it is competitive with quicksort. (It's definitely competitive with insertion sort for large inputs, particularly large inputs in reverse order.)

You can see [pseudocode for standard heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Pseudocode) in Wikipedia. My pseudocode below differs in that it doesn't require the size of the array as a parameter, but instead returns it as the result. It also uses 1-based vectors rather than 0-based, since you are using Lua, so `a` is assume to run from `a[1]` to `a[count]` for some value of `count`.

```
 procedure heapsort(a):
     input: an array of comparable elements
     output: the number of elements in the array.

     (Heapify successive prefixes of the array)
     count ← 1
     while a has an element indexed by count:
         siftup(a, count)
         count ← count + 1
     count ← count - 1

     (Extract the sorted list from the heap)
     i ← count
     while i > 1:
         swap(a, 1, i)
         i ← i - 1
         siftdown(a, i)

     return count
```

`siftup` and `siftdown` are the standard heap functions, here presented in the 1-based version. The code provided uses a standard optimization in which the sifting is done with a single rotation instead of a series of swaps; this cuts the number of array references significantly. (The `swap` in the `heapsort` procedure could be integrated into `siftdown` for a slight additional savings but it obscures the algorithm. If you wanted to use this optimization, change `val ← a[1]` to `val ← a[count + 1]; a[count + 1] ← a[1]` and remove the `swap` from `heapsort`.)

In a 1-based heap, the parent of node `i` is node `floor(i/2)` and the children of node `i` are nodes `2i` and `2i+1`. Recall that the heap constraint requires that every node be no less than its parent. (That produces a minheap, which is used to produce a descending sort. If you want an ascending sort, you need a maxheap, which means changing the three value comparisons below from `>` to `<`.)

```
procedure siftup(a, count):
    input: a vector of length count, of which the first count - 1
           elements satisfy the heap constraint.
    result: the first count elements of a satisfy the heap constraint.

    val ← a[count]
    loop:
        parent ← floor(count / 2)
        if parent == 0 or val > a[parent]:
            a[count] ← val
            return
        else
            a[count] ← a[parent]
            count ← parent

procedure siftdown(a, count):
    input: a vector of length count which satisfies the heap constraint
           except for the first element.
    result: the first count elements of a satisfy the heap constraint.

    val ← a[1]
    parent ← 1
    loop :
        child ← 2 * parent
        if child < count and a[child] > a[child + 1]:
            child ← child + 1
        if count < child or not (val > a[child]):
            a[parent] ← val
            return
        else
            a[parent] ← a[child]
            parent ← child
```

Comment: @soniex2: Yes, inplace

Comment: @rici Could you provide an example? I'm not sure what you mean with "iteratively insert into a growing heap".

Comment: @soniex2: insertion sort consists of iteratively inserting elements into a growing sorted list. That is why it is called insertion sort. In this heapsort we do the same thing but inserting into a heap, which is O(log n).  Then we build the sorted list backwards from the end by repeatedly removing the first (smallest) element of the heap.

Comment: @SoniEx2: Oops, you're right. I think the fix is obvious, don't you? (But I fixed it)

Comment: I can't seem to get your code to work. It's outputting `{7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, nil, 1, 1, 8, 3, 4, nil, nil, 1}` when I give it `{6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4, nil, 1, 1, 8, 3, 4, nil, nil, 1}`.

Comment: @SoniEx2: Yeah, `siftup` failed to place the value if it fell off the end of the loop.

Comment: Is this meant to sort ascendingly or descendingly?

Comment: @SoniEx2: largest to smallest. If you want to go the otherway, change the comparisons with val (both of them) and the comparison between a[child] and a[child + 1].

Comment: You should probably mention that in the answer.

Comment: @SoniEx2: I guess. By the way, I don't understand why you say that the fact that heapsort has two parts makes it not a valid answer. The heapsort I present doesn't do an additional scan; it notices the end of the array while building the heap. (This algorithm is close to Williams' original algorithm, before Floyd figured out how to heapify in guaranteed O(n). But subsequent analysis suggests that Williams' algorithm runs in O(n) *average* time, so it's still reasonable.)